# Как включить всплывающие подсказки в MPLAB X IDE v5.00?

Tags: pic

Как включить всплывающие подсказки в MPLAB X IDE v5.00?

Во многих видео я наблюдаю, что есть такая функция, например в этом видео: https://youtu.be/9kzu_eoKQKo?t=3m46s

Или вот картинка: [image: Всплывающая подсказка]
У меня почему-то такого нет.

Как это включить?

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался, переустановил среду, теперь работает:
CTRL+SPACE